# Values in NSMutableArray seem to spontaneously change. How can this be?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsmutablearray, uicollectionview, uicolor

I'm feeding background colors to the cells of a `UICollectionView` from an `NSMutableArray`, `rainbowArray`, which is populated with `UIColors` using this [very elegant code from BJ Homer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652762/ios-rainbow-colors-array):

```
float INCREMENT = 0.04;

for (float hue = 0.0; hue < 1.0; hue += INCREMENT)
{
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue
                                saturation:1.0
                                brightness:1.0
                                     alpha:1.0];
    [rainbowArray addObject:color];
    NSLog(@"color in rainbow is %@",color);
}
```

Works great! `NSLog'd`output proves the colors are there. However, when I go to actually apply the colors to my `UICollectionViewCells`, `NSLogs` demonstrate that the colors have somehow changed back to `colorWithHue` values of `1 0 0 1`.

Here's the code from my `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, simplified because I'm sharing my delegate methods between two CVs:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (collectionView == self.usedColorsCollectionView)
    {
       ...        
    }


    else if (collectionView == self.pickerCollectionView)
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"pickerCell";

        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


        for (UIColor *thisColor in rainbowArray)
        {
            NSLog(@"Somehow color has changed to %@, and is being applied to cell",thisColor);

            [cell setBackgroundColor:thisColor];

            [cell.layer setCornerRadius:18.0f];
            [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

            return cell;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the log, also simplified, first the values at the time they're created and inserted into the array:

```
2014-08-24 22:38:24.936 WMDGx[26662:90b] color in rainbow is UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1
2014-08-24 22:38:24.937 WMDGx[26662:90b] color in rainbow is UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.24 0 1
2014-08-24 22:38:24.938 WMDGx[26662:90b] color in rainbow is UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.48 0 1
2014-08-24 22:38:24.939 WMDGx[26662:90b] color in rainbow is UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.72 0 1
2014-08-24 22:38:24.940 WMDGx[26662:90b] color in rainbow is UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.96 0 1
2014-08-24 22:38:24.940 WMDGx[26662:90b] color in rainbow is UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.8 1 0 1
2014-08-24 22:38:24.941 WMDGx[26662:90b] color in rainbow is UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.56 1 0 1
2014-08-24 22:38:24.941 WMDGx[26662:90b] color in rainbow is UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.32 1 0 1

...
```

Here are the values at the time they're applied to the cells:

```
2014-08-24 22:38:24.959 WMDGx[26662:90b] Somehow color has changed to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1, and is being applied to cell
2014-08-24 22:38:24.960 WMDGx[26662:90b] Somehow color has changed to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1, and is being applied to cell
2014-08-24 22:38:24.961 WMDGx[26662:90b] Somehow color has changed to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1, and is being applied to cell
2014-08-24 22:38:24.961 WMDGx[26662:90b] Somehow color has changed to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1, and is being applied to cell
2014-08-24 22:38:24.962 WMDGx[26662:90b] Somehow color has changed to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1, and is being applied to cell
2014-08-24 22:38:24.963 WMDGx[26662:90b] Somehow color has changed to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1, and is being applied to cell
2014-08-24 22:38:24.964 WMDGx[26662:90b] Somehow color has changed to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1, and is being applied to cell
2014-08-24 22:38:24.964 WMDGx[26662:90b] Somehow color has changed to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1, and is being applied to cell
2014-08-24 22:38:24.965 WMDGx[26662:90b] Somehow color has changed to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1, and is being applied to cell
2014-08-24 22:38:24.965 WMDGx[26662:90b] Somehow color has changed to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1, and is being applied to cell
2014-08-24 22:38:24.966 WMDGx[26662:90b] Somehow color has changed to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1, and is being applied to cell
```

And here's a screenshot of the result:

[image]

The cells in question are the big red ones, which should be multicolored.

I've been trying to figure this out for hours. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

All fixed! I used the code supplied by @Paulw11, but thanks also to @Shan and @Ramshad for some syntax I'll have to read up on as it was unfamiliar to me.

It looks like this now:

[image]

after I added this code ([posted by @neilsbot in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428422/how-can-i-modify-a-uicolors-hue-brightness-and-saturation)) to flesh out the array of colors, which now contains 68 color wells.

```
float INCREMENT = 0.06;

for (float hue = 0.0; hue < 1.0; hue += INCREMENT)
{
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue
                                saturation:1.0
                                brightness:1.0
                                     alpha:1.0];

    CGFloat oldHue, saturation, brightness, alpha ;

    BOOL gotHue = [color getHue:&oldHue saturation:&saturation brightness:&brightness alpha:&alpha ];

    if (gotHue)
    {
        UIColor * newColor = [ UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:0.7 brightness:brightness alpha:alpha ];
        UIColor * newerColor = [ UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:0.5 brightness:brightness alpha:alpha ];
        UIColor * newestColor = [ UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:0.3 brightness:brightness alpha:alpha ];

        [rainbowArray addObject:color];
        [rainbowArray addObject:newColor];
        [rainbowArray addObject:newerColor];
        [rainbowArray addObject:newestColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: use this instead of loop `[cell setBackgroundColor:[rainbowArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row % rainbowArray.count]];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `return` in your for loop, so you are always returning the first element from the array, which is `1 0 0 1`.

What you want is

```
else if (collectionView == self.pickerCollectionView) {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"pickerCell";

        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [cell setBackgroundColor:[rainbowArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

        [cell.layer setCornerRadius:18.0f];
        [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

         return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`cellForItemAtIndexPath` will trigger for each cell. So just use `indexPath.row % rainbowArray.count` as the array index to get the color. Also make sure to remove the `return` statement from the loop.

Modify your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` as

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (collectionView == self.usedColorsCollectionView)
    {
       ...        
    }
    else if (collectionView == self.pickerCollectionView)
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"pickerCell";

        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        UIColor *thisColor = [rainbowArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row % rainbowArray.count)]; //this will repeat the colors from begning if they end.

        [cell setBackgroundColor:thisColor];
        [cell.layer setCornerRadius:18.0f];
        [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }

   return cell;
}
```