# Swift : Append Characters in Attributed String

Tags: ios, swift, append, nsattributedstring

I want to change color to all characters in string. But my code is giving just last character in string. I want to append characters in attributed string. How can I do this ?

My Code :

```
func test(){
            var str:String = "test string"

            for i in 0...count(str)-1{
                var test = str[advance(str.startIndex, i)]
                var attrString = NSAttributedString(string: toString(test), attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: rainbowColors()])
                label.attributedText = attrString
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case you don't need to append characters if you want each character to have the same rainbow color. You could do the following:

```
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: rainbowColors()])
```

If you want to append characters you need to use NSMutableAttributedString. It has a method called append.

Given the fact that you want a different color for each index do the following:

```
var str:String = "test string"

var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
for (index, character) in enumerate(str) {
  attributedString.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string:  String(character), attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: colorForIndex(index)]))
}

label.attributedText = attributedString
```

colorForIndex is a function you need to implement to get the rainbow color for that particular index

```
func colorForIndex(index: Int) -> UIColor {
  let color = // your function to get the color
  return color
}
```

If you need help to implement that function take a look at this question [iOS rainbow colors array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652762/ios-rainbow-colors-array)

Comment: No, I want each every character to have different color.

Comment: Worked well ! I didn't know enumerate function.  Thanks for helping. You rock ! :)